# Determinant of correlation matrix of autoregressive model

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, st.statistics, determinants

I wonder if there is a paper that can point out how to compute the determinant of a $d \times d$ autoregressive correlation matrix of the form

$$R = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & r & \cdots & r^{d-1}\\
r & 1 & \cdots & r^{d-2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
r^{d-1} & r^{d-2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is the particular case of Theorem 1 in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383741/is-this-determinant-always-non-negative/1384516#1384516 when all the $p_i$ are equal to $r$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The determinant of this matrix is $(1-r^2)^{d-1}$.  This can be proven by induction on $d$  using the block matrix identity $\det \pmatrix{A & B\cr C & D} = \det(A) \det(D - C A^{-1} B)$, where $A$ is the top left $(d-1) \times (d-1)$ submatrix.  Note that $$A \pmatrix{0\cr \ldots\cr 0\cr r\cr} = B$$
so $D - C A^{-1} B = 1 - r^2$.

Comment: This is a correct answer I misread the OP

Answer (score 1):

The method of [Dodgson's evaluation of determinants](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v4i2r22) offers a simple inductive (recursive) proof.

If we denote your determinant by $R_d$, the above technique leads to
$$R_d=\frac{R_{d-1}^2-0^2}{R_{d-2}}=\frac{(1-r^2)^{2d-4}}{(1-r^2)^{d-3}}=(1-r^2)^{d-1},$$
since the top right-most (and bottom left-most) matrices of size $(d-1)\times(d-1)$ have vanishing determinant.

Answer (score 0):

A thorough discussion is contained in

> Finch, P. D. "On the covariance determinants of moving-average and
>   autoregressive models." Biometrika 47.1/2 (1960): 194-196. [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2332974)

But it is more common to write it in form of product of conditional densities $f(x_2\mid x_1)f(x_3\mid x_1,x_2)\cdots $ and consider each update sequentially to discuss the behavior of the covariance matrix.